# Java Class to execute in JButton MouseClicked

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jbutton, actionlistener

I am new to Java. With this class I can open a pdf file:

```
public class ViewPdf {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Process p = 
      Runtime.getRuntime()
        .exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler c:/pdf/mypdf.pdf");
    p.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Done.");
  }
}
```

Now a want to use a Jbutton mouse event to fire this class and open that pdf. I'm working in Netbeans can someone give me some help?

NewJFrame.java

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /** Creates new form NewJFrame */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jButton1MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout =
            new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, 
                layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(217, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(108, 108, 108))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(67, 67, 67)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(210, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    // End of variables declaration

}
```

Thanks in advance...^^

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, you may be able to use [`open()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29) in your button handler.

Answer (score 1):

The place where you have

```
// TODO add your handling code here:
```

You can simply add your code to execute the PDF open

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler c:/pdf/mypdf.pdf"); p.waitFor(); System.out.println("Done.");
```

Comment: do i need to import something cause when i do tha, it shows something like this "unreported exception java.io.IOException;unreported exception java.lang.InterruptedException"...i tired to import io.*; and lang.*; but nothing happens...thanks BTW Codemwnci ^^

Comment: @jayson villa esco You have to put the `Process p  = Runtime...` statement in a `try-catch` block: `try { Process p = Runtime... ; } catch(Exception e) { System.err.println(e.getMessage()); }`